# GIT push all branches in subdirectory to other repo

Tags: git, git-branch

We've got a setup with multiple GIT repos and would like to do following with an automated process

```
repo1/specificbranch
|-branch1
|-branch2
|-branchn
```

to

```
repo2/organisation/specificbranch
|-branch1
|-branch2
|-branchn
```

remotes have been setup, but I've got a hard time figuring out the command to perform.

Comment: just a `git push -u origin branchn` in each path would not be enough?

Comment: No, we have to specify the subdirectory in the source as well as another structure for the destination. I thought it would be something like `git push repo2 specificbranch/*:organisation/specificbranch/`

Answer (score 0):

```
for repo_dir in repo1/specificbranch repo2/organisation/specificbranch
do
    pushd $repo_dir
    git push origin --all
    popd
done
```

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: Git-Bash provides git and bash (`for`, `pushd` and `popd` are bash's builtin commands).